# How to update a Rails app and avoid old caching by browsers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

During development of my chess rails app I have encountered a few times where after updating my Rails app on the next visit the Chrome browser was displaying the chessboard mangled and hitting refresh in the browser didn't fix the problem. I had to manually disable cache in Chrome and refresh to fix things. Maybe something about the css for the chessboard div's was screwed up I don't know. Sorry but I don't have a more detailed report of the problem.

If this can happen to me during development, then surely the users of my website will encounter this old caching problem and see a broken site. Does anyone have an idea of what was going on and how to prevent this?

Comment: Pleas define "something broken". If we can't reproduce the problem you're seeing, then it makes it very hard for us to know what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3.2, asset pipeline takes care of caching for your CSS and JS.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Take a look at the above link to check it out. If you are not using Rails 3.2 use some kind of fingerprinting technique undo the caching.